# Is is possible to run a python project in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-import

I'm trying to run a project on google colab's GPU. Now like a typical project I have the project divided into sub-folders and various `.py` scripts. For an example, my project structure is like:

```
test_project
    ├── module1.py
    ├── module2.py
    ├── run
    │   ├── run2.py
    │   └── run.py
    ├── tools
    │   └── tool.py
    └── utils
        ├── util1.py
        └── util2.py
```

The file I want to execute is `run.py`. Also, I have `__init__.py` (empty) files in all the folders.

Now, I know I can do `sys.path.insert(1, 'test_project')` and make this importable in colab notebook, but the problem is when I do something like

```
from test_project.module1 import foo
```

The import fails yelling

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'module1' from 'test_project'`.
```

Though, `import test_project` works.

Does anyone has any idea on how can I import all the packages and functions inside them just like I'd be able to import when `test_project` is installed with `pip install`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount your project in Google Drive.

1. Store mylib.py in your Drive
2. Open a new Colab
3. Open the (left)side panel, select Files view
4. Click `Mount Drive` then `Connect to Google Drive`
5. Copy it by `!cp drive/MyDrive/mylib.py .`
6. `import mylib`

Another solution it might work is

import sys
import os

```
py_file_location = "/content/drive/My Drive"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(py_file_location))
```

Now you can import it as a module in notebook for that location.

```
import what you want
```

Comment: The 6 steps you mention, what is different in there from directly uploading `mylib.py` to session storage except for it will get deleted after disconnecting runtime? And, I already mentioned that I tried adding to `sys.path`. Didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way is, you can follow the below steps,

**Step1**: Mount the drive, by clicking on the left navigation

[image]

**Step2**: Type the pwd command to check the current working directory

[image]

**Step3**: Use the below command to change the working directory, that is you can specify the path where your python project folder is location

```
import os
import sys
#list the current working dir
os.getcwd()
#change the current working dir
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/<Give project folder>')
```

**Step4**: Run the below command to check if the project folder successfully imported or you can run **pwd** to verify the current working directory

```
!ls
```

The main advantage of this approach is you can work with more than multiple python scripts or files